# if $\left\lfloor\dfrac{2^n}{n}\right\rfloor $is a power of $2$,then $n$ is also a power of $2$?

Tags: number-theory

> If $n$ is a positive integer such that $n\ge 4$ and $\left\lfloor\dfrac{2^n}{n}\right\rfloor$ is a power of $2$; then $n$ is also a power of $2$.

Example  $n=4,n=8,16,\cdots,2^k$, then $\dfrac{2^n}{n}=\dfrac{2^{2^k}}{2^k}=2^{2^k-k}$

But why $n\neq 2^k$?

Comment: If $n$ is no power of two than $\lfloor\frac{2^n}{n}\rfloor$ is strictly smaller than
$\frac{2^n}{n},$ because $n$ has a prime factor $p>2$.

Comment: your idea maybe usefull,but I can't use your idea to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2^k<n<2^{k+1}$, then $2^n/2^{k+1}<2^n/n<2^n/2^k$, so the number is strictly between two powers of 2.  So you just have to check that $2^n/n>1+2^n/2^{k+1}$.
$$\frac{2^n}n-\frac{2^n}{2^{k+1}}\geq\frac{2^n}n-\frac{2^n}{n+1}=\frac{2^n}{n(n+1)}>1$$
and the final inequality follows easily by induction:
Firstly, $2^5=32>30=5(5+1)$.
If $2^n>n(n+1)$ then $2^{n+1}=2(2^n)>2n(n+1)>(n+2)(n+1)$

Answer (score 1):

If

$$\left\lfloor \frac{2^n}{n} \right\rfloor = 2^k$$

Then

$$2^k \leq \frac{2^n}{n} < 2^k +1$$

$$n\leq 2^{n-k}< n + \frac{n}{2^k}$$

Now it's clear that :

- $n>k$, so $2^{n-k}$ is an integer
- $n \leq 2^k$, or else $\frac{2^n}{n} > 2^k+1$ (this would need a little analysis to prove rigourously, just consider the function $f(x) = 2^x - x(2^k+1)$ )

So you get

$$n\leq 2^{n-k}< n + 1$$

And this imply that $n = 2^{n-k}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2^t}{n} = qn+r,$ $0\le r\le\frac{n-1}{n}.$

So $$\left \lfloor \frac{2^t}{n} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor qn+r \right \rfloor = qn=2^k.$$

It implies that if $p|n$ for some prime $p$ then $p|2^k$ and $p=2$.